# how to support phones and tables using reactnative in android?

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native. I am a native android developer. In native android, different images/layouts can be used for different screen size/densities phones and for tablets. Layouts/images can also be changed when the orientation of the phone changes. So is it possible to achieve this in reacting native? and if yes how?

Thanks in advance,

Krishna

Answer (score 0):

[This is an opinion (and experience) based answer, thus may be a bit out of scope of Stack Overflow]

Yes it is. It's possible to add different set of assets for different resolutions and pixel ratios. (See: **/[app-name]/android/app/src/main/res/**)

It's also possible to get `Dimensions` and `PixelRatio` for layout specific sets. If you need (and you probably need) to do relative positioning, flexible layouts etc, then these + Flexbox helps you.

So I suggest you to start by doing something simple and playing with these. In addition, do some googling about the topic, there are blog posts, 3rd party components and other resources available.